# react-native TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.navigator.push')

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I was trying this react-native tutorial for android:
https://www.raywenderlich.com/126063/react-native-tutorial

I'm having problems with navigtor. The first screen (SearchPage) works fine, but when trying to .push to the next it gives me the following error:

**Something bad happened TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.navigator.push')**

Main:

```
render () {
 return(
  <Navigator
    initialRoute={{id: 'SearchPage'}}
    renderScene={this.renderScene.bind(this)}
    />
 );
}

renderScene(route, navigator) {
 switch (route.id) {
  case 'SearchPage':
   return (
    <SearchPage navigator={navigator} />
   );
   case 'TestScreen':
    return (
     <TestScreen navigator={this.props.navigator} />
   );}
```

SearchPage:

```
_executeQuery(query) {
 this.setState({ isLoading: true });
 fetch(query)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(json => this._handleResponse(json.response).bind(this))
  .catch(error =>
     this.setState({
      isLoading: false,
      message: 'Something bad happened ' + error
   }));
}

_handleResponse(response) {
  this.setState({ isLoading: false , message: '' });
  if (response.application_response_code.substr(0, 1) === '1') {
    this.props.navigator.push({
      id: 'TestScreen',
    });
  } else {
    this.setState({ message: 'Location not recognized; please try again.'});
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: in Main component in `renderScene` function, from where are you getting the `navigator` parameter and sending to SearchPage component? is that proper? put a console log there.

Answer (score 0):

It's a scope issue I think. Try using es6 fat arrows :

```
renderScene = (route, navigator) => {
 switch (route.id) {
  case 'SearchPage':
   return (
    <SearchPage navigator={navigator} />
   );
   case 'TestScreen':
    return (
     <TestScreen navigator={navigator} />
   );
}
```

Notice I've changed in the TestScreen case this.props.navigator by navigator.

```
_executeQuery = (query) => {
 this.setState({ isLoading: true });
 fetch(query)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(json => this._handleResponse(json.response))
  .catch(error =>
     this.setState({
      isLoading: false,
      message: 'Something bad happened ' + error
   }));
}

_handleResponse = (response) => {
  this.setState({ isLoading: false , message: '' });
  if (response.application_response_code.substr(0, 1) === '1') {
    this.props.navigator.push({
      id: 'TestScreen',
    });
  } else {
    this.setState({ message: 'Location not recognized; please try again.'});
  }
}
```

Comment: Now it gives me the same error, but with an underscore: **undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this.props.navigator.push')**

Comment: Maybe check your component's props (do a `console.log(this.props);`) before the call to `this.props.navigator.push` and see what is the output...

Comment: only gives me: {rootTag: 1, importantForAccessibility: 'auto'}