# React Native: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this.props.data.map')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I wonder if React Native has a bug that needs fixing that gives the following error:

> React Native: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating
> '_this.props.data.map')

I am pretty good at this and yet I cannot seem to resolve why I am getting this error when I put together this component:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { View, Animated } from "react-native";

class Swipe extends Component {
  renderCards() {
    return this.props.data.map(item => {
      return this.props.renderCard(item);
    });
  }

  render() {
    return <View>{this.renderCards()}</View>;
  }
}

export default Swipe;
```

I have checked and double checked through various debugging practices that the problem is not with my action creator or reducer and after various refactors I got those working correctly.

I decided to do the above component from scratch whereas before I was reusing another component and yet I still get the above error.

I ask if it's a bug with RN because someone else [posted a similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37433499/react-native-typeerror-undefined-is-not-an-object-evaluating-this-props-navig) but they did not get the answer they needed.

It is not a scope issue with `this` because if I refactor it like so:

```
renderCards = () => {
    return this.props.data.map(item => {
      return this.props.renderCard(item);
    });
  };
```

It does absolutely nothing for me, same error message. The message saying is not an object is confusing too, it's an array and `map()` can only iterate through arrays, so not sure what not being an object has to do with it.

The above component is being called in this screen:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { View, Text } from "react-native";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import Swipe from "../components/Swipe";

class DeckScreen extends Component {
  renderCard(job) {
    return (
      <Card title={job.title}>
        <View style={styles.detailWrapper}>
          <Text>{job.company}</Text>
          <Text>{job.post_date}</Text>
        </View>
        <Text>
          {job.description.replace(/<span>/g, "").replace(/<\/span>/g, "")}
        </Text>
      </Card>
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Swipe data={this.props.jobs} renderCard={this.renderCard} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = {
  detailWrapper: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    justifyContent: "space-around",
    marginBottom: 10
  }
};

function mapStateToProps({ jobs }) {
  return { jobs: jobs.listing };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(DeckScreen);
```

This is what the action creator looks like:

```
import axios from "axios";
// import { Location } from "expo";
import qs from "qs";

import { FETCH_JOBS, LIKE_JOB } from "./types";
// import locationify from "../tools/locationify";

const JOB_ROOT_URL = "https://authenticjobs.com/api/?";

const JOB_QUERY_PARAMS = {
  api_key: "5634cc46389d0d872723b8c46fba672c",
  method: "aj.jobs.search",
  perpage: "10",
  format: "json"
};

const buildJobsUrl = () => {
  const query = qs.stringify({ ...JOB_QUERY_PARAMS });
  return `${JOB_ROOT_URL}${query}`;
};

export const fetchJobs = (region, callback) => async dispatch => {
  try {
    const url = buildJobsUrl();
    let { data } = await axios.get(url);
    dispatch({ type: FETCH_JOBS, payload: data });
    callback();
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
};

export const likeJob = job => {
  return {
    payload: job,
    type: LIKE_JOB
  };
};
```

and reducer:

```
import { FETCH_JOBS } from "../actions/types";

const INITIAL_STATE = {
  listing: []
};

export default function(state = INITIAL_STATE, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_JOBS:
      return action.payload;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

and the `combineReducer` is setup correctly as well:

```
import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import auth from "./auth_reducer";
import jobs from "./jobs_reducer";
import likedJobs from "./likes_reducer";

export default combineReducers({
  auth,
  jobs,
  likedJobs
});
```

The `listing: []` is based off the structure of the response I get back. When I console.log(data);, the actual data I care about is inside of `listing` property. So I set up the `INITIAL_STATE` to default listing to be an empty array with the intent to ensure I could map over the array and not worry about the case where I have not yet fetched the list of jobs. When I go to the API endpoint directly you can see it below:

[image]

Comment: where is `props.data` defined?

Comment: In what format data are you receiving from the server?

Comment: @Codesingh, `format: 'json'`.

Comment: listing key is available in the response ?

Comment: @Codesingh, yes, I added it in my OP so you can see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is in your reducer. Please refer the below changes:

```
import { FETCH_JOBS } from "../actions/types";

const INITIAL_STATE = {
  listing: []
};

export default function(state = INITIAL_STATE, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_JOBS:
      const { listings } = action.payload
      return {...state, listing: listings.listing}
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is simply that `this.props.jobs` is undefined. Your initial state is defined as `{ listing: [] }`, however you mapStateToProps do `{ jobs: ... }`.

Try changing initialState to `{ jobs: [] }`, so that it always work on your first rendering.

I think your mapStateToProps should be:

```
mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return { jobs: listings.listing }
}
```

EDIT
Actually, it could be even better if you 'name' your state correctly in your reducer, like:

```
const INITIAL_STATE = { jobs: [] }

export default function(state = INITIAL_STATE, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_JOBS:
      const jobs = action.payload.listings.listing
      return { ...state, jobs };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Then in your mapStateToProps:

```
mapStateToProps = ({ jobs }) => {
  return { jobs }
}
```

Comment: the `listing: []` is based off the structure of the response I get back. When I `console.log(data);`, the actual data I care about is inside of `listing` property. So I set up the `INITIAL_STATE` to default `listing` to be an empty array with the intent to ensure I could map over the array and not worry about the case where I have not yet fetched the list of jobs.

Comment: However you're accessing `this.props.jobs` on your first render. The error is happening after or before you fetch the data?

Also, after fetching data (in your action creator) you are sending { listings: listing } as payload but your mapToProps is getting `jobs.listing`, am I wrong?

Answer (score -1):

```
function mapStateToProps({ jobs }) {
```

`return { jobs: jobs.listing };
}`

the above is making confusion for you try the below one

try to put

`function mapStateToProps( state ) {
  return { jobs: state.jobs.listing };
}`

as you have defined your reducer as follow

```
export default combineReducers({
```

`auth,
  jobs,
  likedJobs
});`

**jobs** is your variable to access **jobs reducer**

Comment: @Daniel try this one :-)

Comment: and try to use ** ES6**  formate it will be easy to understand the functions.   
`const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    miniStatement: state.miniStatement.miniStatement,
  }
}`

Comment: I'm afraid this is wrong: `mapStateToProps` has param `state` not an object containing it, in your code `state` would be undefined. Also please format correctly your answers.

Comment: @josemigallas sorry just didn't see those braces Thanks